# how can I show the data automatically after I input the data into a textbox? C#

Tags: c#

I  want when I enter the bar-code number without pressing any buttons automatically the data show up,and the quantity be 1 by default i tried the same with `txt_no` but it needs to press the enter button also.

here is the form.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VC3G.png)

and here is the code:

```
 private void txtno_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {




                txtqty.Enabled = true;
                txtqty.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void txtqty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
                try
                {
                    string txt="Select * from products where id = '"+txtno.Text+"'";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(txt,con);
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (r.Read())
                    {
                        int price = int.Parse(txtqty.Text.Trim()) * int.Parse(r[4].ToString());
                        totalprice = totalprice + price;


                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.RowCount, r[0], r[1], txtqty.Text.Trim(), r[4], price);
                    }
                    lbitems.Text = "" + (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) + "";
                    lbtotal.Text = "" + totalprice + "";

                    con.Close();


                    }



                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error From Database");


                }
                txtno.Focus();
                txtno.Clear();

                txtqty.Enabled = false;
                txtqty.Clear();


            }

            }
```

Comment: what is format off bar-code number? length?

Comment: its id   INT i just change the name to barcode in the form

Comment: What is expected length of bar-code? In image I can see 1234, so does bar-code have 4 digits always ?

Comment: Please don't build a sql query this way, use parameters. Read up on "sql injection"

Comment: no, its up to the barcode scanner..

Comment: When you say "without pressing any buttons" it leads me to believe that your application should be listening for an Event that is raised by the Bar Code Scanner integration piece. Investigate what the bar code scanner API or software developer kit provides to see what events you can handle in your application to make this automatic.

Comment: Can the bar code scanner be configured to send a carriage-return after the scanned data? Otherwise you're stuck with a solution like adding an event handler to detect the initial input, setting a timer to a short interval to allow more characters from the scanner and when the timer expires assuming that it must be complete. A somewhat fragile design.

Answer (score 0):

You need `TextChanged` event handler for txtno(i.e. Bar-code textbox).
Add `TextChanged` event handler for txtno as below.

And as suggested by @HansKeﬆing, you should sanitize inputs to avoid sql injection.

```
    private void txtno_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {       
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtno.Text))
        {
            txtqty.Enabled = true;
            txtqty.Focus();

            Search();
        }
        else
        {
            txtqty.Enabled = false;     
        }
    }

    private void txtqty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            Search();
        }
    }

    private void Search()
    {
            try
            {
                string txt = "Select * from products where id = '" + txtno.Text + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(txt, con);
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (r.Read())
                {
                    int price = int.Parse(txtqty.Text.Trim()) * int.Parse(r[4].ToString());
                    totalprice = totalprice + price;
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataGridView1.RowCount, r[0], r[1], txtqty.Text.Trim(), r[4], price);
                }

                lbitems.Text = "" + (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1) + "";
                lbtotal.Text = "" + totalprice + "";
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error From Database");
            }

            txtno.Focus();
            txtno.Clear();
            txtqty.Enabled = false;
            txtqty.Clear();
    }
```